# Can I put "Powered by Google" anywhere in the page of my site (footer)?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm planning to use Google Places API on some pages in my site and I have read the documentation but it doesn't specifically say where to put the "Powered by Google" logo?

I am not using Google Maps on pages where users can do location autocomplete searching. In this case, do I put it at the bottom of the autocomplete results? Or I can just put the "Powered by Google" logo at the footer of my site? I think it was required before to put it at the bottom of search results but I'm hoping if I can just put it at the footer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it doesn't say, then don't worry about where to put it.

Comment: What about reading the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#terms_of_use_and_privacy_policy_requirements)?